# Calculating the Fisher criterion in Python

Tags: python, statistics, machine-learning, stat

Is there a python module that when given two vectors x and y, where y is a two-class (0,1), it calculates the Fisher criterion, as shown in the formula here http://compbio.soe.ucsc.edu/genex/genexTR2html/node12.html

Please note that I am not looking to apply Fisher's linear discriminant, only the Fisher criterion :).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not as far as I can tell, but you could write your own (please test that this result is correct, I'm only going by my understanding of the formula).

```
import numpy as np

def fisher_criterion(v1, v2):
    return abs(np.mean(v1) - np.mean(v2)) / (np.var(v1) + np.var(v2))
```

Which gives, for example,

```
>>> fisher_criterion([0, 1, 2], [0, 1])
0.54545454545454553
```

Comment: After reading the formula again, I realized its very easy to implement :) :). What you did seems correct. Thanks a million!

Comment: Isn't the numerator supposed to be squared so the result is unitless?

Answer (score 1):

That looks remarkably like [Linear Discriminant Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis) - if you're happy with that then you're amply catered for with [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_lda_qda.html) and [mlpy](http://mlpy.sourceforge.net/) or one of many SVM packages.